# Poisson distribution and manipulation of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X\sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$. Define $Y=X^2+k$ and obtain the probability mass function $P(Y=y)$. My question is: Can we just do $$P(Y=y)=P(X^2+k=y)=P(X=\sqrt{y-k})$$ or there is some condition that make this wrong?

Comment: Correct.........

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. Consider that you must define $Y$-support too.

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=y]=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{\sqrt{y-k}}}{(\sqrt{y-k})!}$$

$$y=k,k+1,k+4,k+9,k+16,\dots$$

Comment: Thank you! We define $y=k,k+1,\dots$  to get the natural numbers right?

Comment: @Lucascantu : not exactly. $X$ is defined on $N$ Thus $ Y=X^2+k$ is defined in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. As an example,  if k=3 the support of Y  is $3,4,7,12,19,\dots$

Comment: Get it. Thank you!